# reading and updating record and doing addition

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a field called force. Its by default a null field. I want to add 1 everytime I run an if block. here is my code sample

```
if($somecondition){
$array = array();
$array[] = $this->Model->read(null, 1); 
$array['force']++;
$this->Model->updateAll(array('Model.complete' => 1, 'Model.force' => $array['force']),array('Model.completed IS NULL'));
}
```

I am getting an error of undefined variable $array. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are very new to Cake (and maybe even PHP)

> ```
> if($somecondition){
>   $array = $this->Model->read('force',1);
>   if($array['Model']['force']===NULL)$array['Model']['force'] = 0;
>   $array['Model']['force']++;
>   $array['Model']['complete']=1;
>   $this->Model->save($array);
> }
> ```

It you can, change the default value of 'force' to 0 in the DB, so you don't have to check for that here.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `$array['force']` to 0 before incrementing it.